# java -classpath ./sqljdbc4.jar myclassname

Tags: java

if I run `java -classpath ./sqljdbc4.jar myclassname` error is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:myclassname

if I run `java myclassname` error is

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

It is on Linux. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't use jar file. It is myclassname.class. Do I　have to use jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The directory or jar containing your classes package tree (i.e. the directory containing the com directory, in the following example) must be in the classpath. And the sqljdbc4.jar must also be. Put both in the classpath:

```
java -cp ../classes:./sqljdbc4.jar com.foo.bar.MyClassName
```

Also note that you need to use the fully qualified name of the main class (as the above example shows), and that class names in Java use CamelCase by convention.

Comment: It should be `-cp` instead of `-jar` like : `java -cp .:./sqljdbc4.jar com.foo.bar.MyClassName`. Also note if its windows, then use `;` instead of `:` when specifying classpath.

Comment: You're right of course. I fixed the answer. Don't even know why I wrote -jar in the first place.